# Expected newline after ":" with a multi-line declaration prettier

Tags: css, sass, prettier

Prettier is formating this part of the code in a scss file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Encode Sans Condensed';
src: url('/pf/resources/fonts/EncodeSansCondensed/EncodeSansCondensed-Thin.ttf') 
format('truetype');
font-weight: 200;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I am getting this error "Expected newline after ":" with a multi-line declaration"
What can I do in the .prettierrc.json file to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The multiline declaration is on the `src` property. Looks like prettier wants this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Encode Sans Condensed';
    src:
      url('/pf/resources/fonts/EncodeSansCondensed/EncodeSansCondensed-Thin.ttf') 
      format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But you could do this instead:

```css
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Encode Sans Condensed';
    src: url('/pf/resources/fonts/EncodeSansCondensed/EncodeSansCondensed-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It may be that your linter is creating formatting incompatible prettier's configuration. Eg: if using stylelint:

`npm install --save-dev stylelint-config-prettier`

Then, append `stylelint-config-prettier` to the `"extends"` array in your `.stylelintrc.* file`. Make sure to put it last, so it will override other configs.

```json
{
  "extends": [
    // other configs ...
    "stylelint-config-prettier"
  ]
}
```

Source: https://github.com/prettier/stylelint-config-prettier

Comment: I am in a react project, I am using prettier, stylelint and eslint. To check the warnings I am using: 
webpack --watch --config ./config/webpack.base.js --env dev --progress
I tried with stylelint-config-prettier but I am still getting the warnings

Comment: Can you simply edit the scss file add the newline as prettier suggests?